# Creating a nestable CSS grid that maintains centering without losing background

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a CSS Grid which centers all its items both horizontally and vertically and maintains a background which takes up the whole grid.

To do this, I am first creating CSS for each item which looks something like this:

```
.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
  background:yellow;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
}
```

The only difference between each item is its item number (in the class), the `grid-area` name, and the background color.  I added `display: grid;` because without it I can't seem to both center *and* have the background color cover the whole grid.  I don't understand why this is, but it seems to work.

My container CSS looks like this:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20vw 20vw 20vw 20vw;
  grid-template-rows: 25vh 25vh 25vh;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header header header header"
    "main main subg sidebar"
    "footer footer footer footer";
}
```

Now when I create the grid everything looks the way I want it to:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"><H1>Header</H1></div>
  <div class="item2">Main</div>
  <div class="item3">Sidebar</div>  
  <div class="item4">Footer</div>
  <div class="item5">X</div>
</div>
```

Now I want to achieve the exact same effect in the central item.  So first I create nearly identical CSS tags for the sub-items and sub-containers.  The only differences are in the naming and changing the dimensions from absolute screen based (vh/vw) to percentages:

```
.sub_item1 {
  grid-area: header1;
  background:yellow;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: grid;
}
...
.sub_container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-rows: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "header1 header1 header1 header1"
    "main1 main1 subg1 sidebar1"
    "footer1 footer1 footer1 footer1";
}
```

I nest the sub-container in the center item in the top-level container:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1"><H1>Header</H1></div>
  <div class="item2">Main</div>
  <div class="item3">Sidebar</div>  
  <div class="item4">Footer</div>
  <div class="item5 sub_container">
    <div class="sub_item1">Header</div>
    <div class="sub_item2">Main</div>
    <div class="sub_item3">Side</div>  
    <div class="sub_item4">Footer</div>
    <div class="sub_item5">X</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have created a [fiddle to demonstrate how it fails](https://jsfiddle.net/41wfbj6L/).  The sub-container does not stretch the background color to fit the cells like the top-level does.

I tried changing the dimensions to screen based (e.g. 5vw, 11vh) and this does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the "item5" class from the sub-container div.

```
  <div class="sub_container">
```

[Here is the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41wfbj6L/1/).